# Errors with reactNative/voice in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

thats my code

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Voice from '@react-native-voice/voice';

export default function App() {
  let [started, setStarted] = useState(false);
  let [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;

    return () => {
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    }
  }, []);
  

  const startSpeechToText = async () => {
    await Voice.start();
    setStarted(true);
  };

  const stopSpeechToText = async () => {
    await Voice.stop();
    setStarted(false);
  };

  const onSpeechResults = (result) => {
    setResults(result.value);
  };

  const onSpeechError = (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!started ? <Button title='Start Speech to Text' onPress={startSpeechToText} /> : undefined}
      {started ? <Button title='Stop Speech to Text' onPress={stopSpeechToText} /> : undefined}
      {results.map((result, index) => <Text key={index}>{result}</Text>)}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

when I run it I keep getting this error

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Voice.startSpeech')]

I tried asking chatGPT but he can't answer it

Packages and import is correct, so I don't know what the error is nor how I can fix it

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works on another version of android, I launched some emulators and it seems that below Android 12 there are problems with Permissions.
On Android 12 and above, my code with react-native-voice works well with expo run:android but I can't find out why once built with expo build:android I still have problems with mic permissions